# Convert hibernate HQL with collection.size to criteria query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteria

For some reason I can never figure out how to do things via criteria api.

I have a HQL:

```
from Track track where size(track.trackTitles) > 1
```

Is it possible to convert it into a criteria query on Track class? If yes, how: what Restriction should I use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Restrictions.sizeGt("trackTitles", 1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Shame on me for not looking javadoc up; tho, their megadocumentation is utterly silent about this.